# When in Managed Package config/development is the namespace absolutely required?

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, isv, configuration

I'm working to develop a process for developing managed code in an unmanaged environment, and I'm unable to find a comprehensive list of places where adding the namespace in config/code is absolutely required.

Does anyone know, or have a resource they can point me to?

My concerns at this point are:

- Dynamic SOQL
- RemoteAction Apex Method reference
- Ajax toolkit Apex Method reference in custom button
- Visualforce URLs constructed as strings rather than PageReferences

Comment: As far as I know, you only need to use the namespace from outside the managed package, i.e. from within it, as far as I'm aware you don't need to use it at all.

Comment: I hope you're right. I've added some concerns to my question.

Comment: Dynamic SOQL is safe, but good point about RemoteAction/Ajax and anything else that is effectively a String in your VF. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a namespace in the following scenarios:

1) The AJAX Toolkit, for fields and objects that exist in your package. There's no convenient workaround if you use this toolkit. Instead, consider using Visualforce remoting in its place, when possible.

2) Visualforce remoting JavaScript using literal function names. The recommended practice to avoid this scenario is to use {!$RemoteAction.className.functionName}, which will automatically include the namespace, if applicable.

3) Custom Links that reference your page from outside of the namespace. A custom button or link with a type of "URL" needs the namespace. When possible, use a Visualforce custom link/button instead. The namespace is automatically supplied in that case.

5) In JavaScript, be aware that JSON strings will have the namespace included when the JSON is generated by the server. This may affect your AJAX/JavaScript inside your Visualforce pages. Similarly, depending on String.valueOf to get the API name of a field or object will also result in the namespace being present, which can cause unpleasant surprises.

6) Web tabs need the namespace, but Visualforce tabs do not, so use the Visualforce tab when possible.

7) Dynamic SOQL (and even static SOQL) automatically assumes the namespace of the current class, so you never need the namespace for those queries. Be aware, however, that this means if you have an object Foo_*c in a managed package, and the installed organization also has an object Foo*_c, you won't be able to query the organization's unmanaged version because of this shadowing effect. The same situation also applies to fields with the same name. Also, note that the namespace will automatically appear in included record types, so you may need to write defensively to prevent confusing your record type with an unmanaged record type by the same name. The same is also true with folders, static resources, etc.

Comment: How about dynamic apex methods? object.put('field__c','some value')

Comment: The system will know that you meant the managed version (because, as mentioned before, you cannot access the unmanaged version of the field). In fact, I have a class in a managed package that uses that mechanism without an issue. However, when possible, I would recommend simply using a Schema.SObjectField token when possible, which is what my newer code does. You can get those tokens from a getDescribe() if you're trying to avoid hard-linking a field into a package.